# Proving a trait for infinite sets that theres a subset $B$ s.t $f(B) \subseteq B$ and showing it doesn't exist for finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> 1. Prove if $A$ is an inifnite set then for all functions $f:A\to A$ there exists a subset $B$ such that $\emptyset\neq B \subsetneq A$ and $f(B) \subseteq B$.
> 2. For a finite set $C$ with $n \gt 1$ elements find a function $g:C\to C$ such that $g(D)\not\subseteq D$ for all $\emptyset\neq D \subsetneq C$. (the trait in question 1 characterizes infinite sets)

1, I tried to prove by counter position, so trying to negate the given statement: for an infinite set $A$ there exists a function $f:A\to A$ such that for every subset $\emptyset\neq B \subsetneq A$ we have $f(B) \not\subseteq B$.

Take some $a_0\in A$ and $B=A\setminus\{a_0\}$, I supposed that $f(B) \not\subseteq B$ so we have some $a\in f(B)$ such that $a\not\in B$, the only such $a$ can be $a_0$. So there exists $b_0\in B$ such that $f(b_0)=a_0$. But I don't know what to do next...

2, let $(c_n)$ be a finite sequence to represent the elements of $C$ (the sequence is for using the indexes). Define a function like so:

$$g(c)=\begin{cases}c_{n+1}&,c=c_n , \ n<|C|-1  \\c_0&, c=c_n, \ n=|C|   \end{cases} \\ c\in C, n\in \mathbb N$$

We know that $D \subsetneq C$ so there has to be $d\in D , \ c\in C\setminus D , \ s.t \ \ g(d)=c$ and because $c\in C\setminus D$ we have $c\not\in D \Rightarrow c\in g(D)$ and from here we know that $g(D)\subsetneq D$ because otherwise, by counter position, we have $g(D)\subset D$ so there have to be for all $c\in g(D)$ also $c\in D$ but we showed that doesn't happen.

Question: can the well ordering theorem help with 2 ?

I'm really not sure about these so any insight or alternative approaches would be appreciated.

Comment: In 1 you cannot "suppose that f(B)⊈B"; this is what you have to prove. But picking $a_0 \in A$ and $a_0 \notin B$ (and you can do this, because B⊊A) you must define your $f$ in such a way that $f(b_0)=a_0$ for some $b_0 \in B$ (and you have it, because $\emptyset \ne B$).

Comment: I think that your approach is the right one. Assume $A$ infinite and $f : A \rightarrow A$ does not satisfy the condition. Let $x_0 \in A$ and let $B_0 = A- \{ x_0 \}$; $B$ is a non empty subset of $A$, so by assumption on $f$ we have $x_1 \in A$ such that $f(x_1)=x_0$. Then let $B_1 = A- \{ x_1 \}$ and $x_2 \in A$ such that $f(x_2)=x_1$ (clearly, $x_1 \ne x_0$). In this way, we will map all subsets of $A$ (except $A$ itself and $\emptyset$) into a countable subset of $A$ itself, contradicting the fact that for $A$ infinite, $\mathcal {P(A)}$ is uncountable.